# Passing data to ajax call on success

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I wanted to pass the data from `json_encode()` function into jquery. And on success I wanted to reload the specific div.

Trigger:

```
<a id="js-delete-file" href="#" data-url="<?php echo site_url('document_items/remove/'. $value['id'].'/'. $value['filename']) ?>">Remove</a>
```

PHP:

```
public function remove ($id=null, $filename) {

    $dir = "_resources/docs/";
    if ($this->doc_item->remove($id)) {
        unlink($dir.$filename);
        $status = 'success';
        $msg = 'File successfully deleted';
    } else {
        $status = 'error';
        $msg = 'Something went wrong when deleting the file, please try again';
      }

      echo json_encode(array('status' => $status, 'msg' => $msg));
  }
```

JQUERY:

```
$('#js-delete-file').click(function(e){

    var url = $(this).attr('data-url');
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: url,
      success: function(result) {
        $('#uploaded-files').html(result);
      },
    });
  });
```

after I click the button it will give me this `{"status":"success","msg":"File successfully deleted"}` instead of the actual html.

Comment: You've stated your desire. You've provided some server side code that looks like it should do the server side part of what you want. You haven't shown us any of the client side code. What's the problem?

Comment: where is your ajax code

Comment: Kindly check my edit. Thanks!

Comment: Now you've provided some JS that looks like it should do the job. What's the problem?

Comment: Still don't know what the problem is. What's not doing what you expect?

Comment: I wanted to display the message passed from json in a div.

Comment: I missed the dataType. My bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use param dataType for access to field status

```
$.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: url,
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(result) {
        if (result.status == 'success') {
          $('#uploaded-files').html(result.msg);
        }
      }
    });
```

Comment: O i missed the dataType. Thanks!

Comment: `dataType` only matters if the server is sending the wrong content-type.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('#js-delete-file').click(function(e){

    var url = $(this).attr('data-url');
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: url,
      success: function(result) {
         var data = JSON.parse(result);
         $('#uploaded-files').html(data.msg);
      },
    });
});
```